# Pandas Data Frame - Merge Two Data Frames based on "InStr" > 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames in Python Pandas.

Data stored in the cells are as follows:

```
DF1
- DatabaseId    Integer
- DatabaseName  String

DF2
- CreateString  String
```

I want to apply the column DataBaseID to any record in DF2 where the DF1.DatabaseName exists within the context of Create String.

```
Example:
DatabaseName = "UserDB"        CreateString = "This create string would fail"
DatabaseName = "UserDB"        CreateString = "This create string has UserDB in it"
```

The first record would fail and not be included in the resulting set.
The second record would succeed and would be in the resulting set.

I've researched a variety of options including `.isin`, and `.contains`, but these have not worked.  This seems to be a 'controlled' Cartesian join with an 'if match found success' condition.  But I haven't been able to find a way to do this, and it efficiently.

Total list size needing to be evaluated are between 100K and 500K each.

***UPDATE***
Added More Example Data:

```
>>> DF1.head(10)
DatabaseID     DatabaseName
0              DB1
1              DB2
2              DB3
3              DB4
...

>>> DF2.head(10)
CreateString
None
None
None
CREATE VIEW DB1.Table1 AS LOC…
None
REPLACE VIEW DB3.Table3...
CREATE VIEW DB3.Table10 AS SELE...
CREATE VIEW DB55.Table999 AS SELEC...
...

Desired Result
DatabaseID      DatabaseName        CreateText
0               DB1                 CREATE VIEW DB1.Table1 AS LOC…
2               DB3                 REPLACE VIEW DB3.Table3...
2               DB3                 CREATE VIEW DB3.Table10 AS SELE...
...
etc...
...
```

Comment: Could you show your *actual* DataFrames?

Comment: To clarify, you want only those entries in DF2 that contain one of the Database Names in DF1's DatabaseName column? Have you tried making a regular expression out of the DatabaseName column and then doing something like DF2.loc[:,'CreateString'].str.contains(regex), where regex is the regular expression made from the DF1 DatabaseName Column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** how to parse table name:

```
In [100]: df2['TableName'] = df2.CreateString.str.extract('\s+(\w+\.\w+)\s+', expand=True)

In [101]: df2
Out[101]:
                            CreateString DatabaseName      TableName
0                                   None          NaN            NaN
1                                   None          NaN            NaN
2                                   None          NaN            NaN
3         CREATE VIEW DB1.Table1 AS LOC…          DB1     DB1.Table1
4                                   None          NaN            NaN
5            REPLACE VIEW DB3.Table3 ...          DB3     DB3.Table3
6     CREATE VIEW DB3.Table10 AS SELE...          DB3    DB3.Table10
7  CREATE VIEW DB55.Table999 AS SELEC...         DB55  DB55.Table999
```

**Original answer:**

you can do it this way:

```
In [83]: df2['DatabaseName'] = df2.CreateString.str.extract('\s+(\w+)\.\w+\s+', expand=True)

In [84]: pd.merge(df2, df1, on='DatabaseName', how='left')
Out[84]:
                            CreateString DatabaseName  DatabaseID
0                                   None          NaN         NaN
1                                   None          NaN         NaN
2                                   None          NaN         NaN
3         CREATE VIEW DB1.Table1 AS LOC…          DB1         0.0
4                                   None          NaN         NaN
5            REPLACE VIEW DB3.Table3 ...          DB3         2.0
6     CREATE VIEW DB3.Table10 AS SELE...          DB3         2.0
7  CREATE VIEW DB55.Table999 AS SELEC...         DB55         NaN
```

Comment: While that works for the database, what if I need the Database||'.'||Tablename?  Is there anyway to do an "INSTR" (instring) type check?  Oracle Example of this located here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm

Comment: @Lee_Str, where do you need it? as a new column?

Comment: Either as a new column OR as the 'filter' for building a new dataframe.  if it is a new column, i will use that to filter the new dataframe.

Comment: @Lee_Str, did it help?

Comment: thank you. yes that did!  I need to bone up on regex.